# Unity gyroscope default position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gyroscope, accelerator

I have a question about gyroscope delault position. I created a game in witch you move space ship foward, back, left, and right by moving the phone(using gyroscope). My problem is that I must hold phone horizontally like on picture 1. If i hold the phone as usual (about 60 degrees to the ground) like on picture 2, the ship goes down. Anyone know how to change default position of the gyroscope, so I can normally hold the phone and steering the ship? I want the ship stationary if my phone is holded at 60 degrees. Otherwise, it move to the titled direction.

[image]

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class Boundaryy
{
    public float xMin, xMax, zMin, zMax;
}

public class PlayerControll1 : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed;
    public float tilt;
    public Boundaryy boundary;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Input.gyro.enabled = true;
        Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
         }

     void FixedUpdate() {

        float xi = Input.gyro.userAcceleration.x;
        float yi = Input.gyro.userAcceleration.y;


        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (xi, 0.0f, yi);
        rigidbody.velocity = movement * speed;

        rigidbody.position = new Vector3 
            (
                Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax), 0.0f, 
                Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax)
                );

        rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0.0f, 0.0f, rigidbody.velocity.x * -tilt);

    }   
}
```

If anybody have a clue how to do this, please help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved a similar problem, although I expect you've now solved this issue I thought I'd share my solution in case others stumble across this question...

At the point you're starting the game you just need to keep a record of a reference point. Then for each calculation involving the current acceleration, deduct the initial reference acceleration value. That will provide you with the adjusted acceleration values taking into account of how the player is holding their device.

```
public class PlayerControll1 : MonoBehaviour {
    ....
    public Vector3 baseAcceleration;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        ...
        baseAcceleration = Input.gyro.userAcceleration;
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {

        float xi = Input.gyro.userAcceleration.x - baseAcceleration.x;
        float yi = Input.gyro.userAcceleration.y - baseAcceleration.y;

        ...
    }   
}
```